# Rotation raytracer camera

Tags: c++, raytracing

I'm writing small raytracer and I want to rotate my camera around some object. So I can achieve this such code:

vecTemp is camera position vector, vecT is the first position (i run this snippet in for loop). Yaw is radian value angle of moved camera.

```cpp
double yaw = degree * (PI / 180.f);
vecTemp.x() = cos(yaw) * vecT.x() - sin(yaw) * vecT.z();
vecTemp.z() = cos(yaw) * vecT.z() + sin(yaw) * vecT.x();
vecTemp.y() = 0;
sett.camera.buildCameraToWorld(vecTemp, { 0, 0, 0} );
sett.camera.rotateY(2*degree);
```

```cpp
void buildCameraToWorld(const arma::dvec3& from, const arma::dvec3& to, const arma::dvec3& tmp = arma::dvec3{ 0, 1, 0 })
   {
      arma::dvec3 forward = arma::normalise(from - to);
      arma::dvec3 right = arma::cross(arma::normalise(tmp), forward);
      arma::dvec3 up = arma::cross(forward, right);

      this->cameraToWorld.zeros();

      this->cameraToWorld(0, 0) = right.x();
      this->cameraToWorld(0, 1) = right.y();
      this->cameraToWorld(0, 2) = right.z();
      this->cameraToWorld(1, 0) = up.x();
      this->cameraToWorld(1, 1) = up.y();
      this->cameraToWorld(1, 2) = up.z();
      this->cameraToWorld(2, 0) = forward.x();
      this->cameraToWorld(2, 1) = forward.y();
      this->cameraToWorld(2, 2) = forward.z();

      this->cameraToWorld(3, 0) = from.x();
      this->cameraToWorld(3, 1) = from.y();
      this->cameraToWorld(3, 2) = from.z();

      this->cameraToWorld = this->cameraToWorld.t();
   }
void rotateY(double yaw)
   {
      yaw = yaw * (PI / 180);
      this->cameraToWorld = this->cameraToWorld * arma::dmat44{ { cos(yaw), 0, sin(yaw), 0},
                                                                {        0, 1,        0, 0},
                                                                {-sin(yaw), 0, cos(yaw), 0},
                                                                {        0, 0,        0, 1} };
   }
```

So, now I don't understand, why i have rotate in Y axis after translation - after buildCameraToWorld i should get a new camera matrix looking at my origin, right? Why i need to rotate by double degree value?

I found some other way to do it - i can rotate the whole world and don't move camera, like in camera from OpenGL, but its good idea for ray tracer?

Comment: What is "yaw"? If it should be value in radians, then why is it not `pi * degree / 180` ?

Comment: @MikeSpencer  added small fix in code, and explenation about yaw. 
I think, that my radians are good ompute, checked with google